# How to disable a notifications bar on android in Unity app?

Tags: android, .net, user-interface, unity-game-engine

[image]

I want to disable android notification bar from code behind in Unity application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't block the notification bar from a user. That is not part of your application. Just like you can't disable the "Home" button from any Android app. It is a system level feature provided by the Android OS, not for any third-party app to control.